# Cannot use UUID as a primary key: Uuid: diesel::Expression is not satisfied

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel, actix-web

I want to have a UUID field as the primary field in a Postgres table, but I get the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `uuid::Uuid: diesel::Expression` is not satisfied
 --> database/src/models.rs:3:35
  |
3 | #[derive(Debug, Clone, Queryable, Insertable)]
  |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::Expression` is not implemented for `uuid::Uuid`
  |
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::expression::AsExpression<diesel::sql_types::Uuid>` for `uuid::Uuid`
```

Some older questions are there about UUID with diesel but none of them are insertable and I am getting the error specifically in that. I am using diesel with actix web.

Here is my model:

```rust
use crate::schema::users;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Queryable, Insertable)]
#[table_name="users"]
pub struct User {
    pub id: uuid::Uuid,
    pub phone: String,
    pub name: String,
    pub password: String,
}
```

And my table schema

```rust
table! {
    users (id) {
        id -> Uuid,
        name -> Text,
        phone -> Text,
        password -> Text,
    }
}
```

I found some old post that suggested that the field might be nullable but `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` in my table up.sql, so it is not nullable.

The table is generated from diesel-cli, do there doesn't seem to be any problem there.

Here is my Cargo.toml

```
diesel = { version = "1.0.0", features = ["postgres", "r2d2", "uuid"] }
uuid = { version = "0.8", features = ["v4"] }
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"
```

Comment: Could you add some more information about which version of `diesel` and `uuid ` you use? Also which feature flags are enabled for `diesel`? This is very likely either a missing feature flag or a version mismatch between the `uuid` version `diesel` uses internally and your `uuid` version.

Comment: Diesel does currently not support `uuid` version 0.8 in it's latest released version, only version 0.7 and below are supported. Additionally you need to use the `uuidv07` feature for support for version 0.7. This will change with the next diesel release.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's always good to see what's in your `Cargo.lock` file and look are pointing for package dependencies.

```
[[package]]
name = "diesel"
version = "1.4.4"
...
 "uuid 0.6.5", <-- It was older version even I've installed newest version of uuid
]
```

as soon as change features to `uuidv07` and run `cargo update` Cargo.lock file also changes. If you want to check which `Uuid` is applied by diesel. It's possible checking it by looking to the source of the `diesel::sql_types::Uuid` to be sure they are using the same versions as `uuid::Uuid`.

P.S: Answer was commented by @weiznich in the question post, just adding little bit detailed information and as an answer post whom, who not read comments and look for answer only

Comment: I am a beginner, uuid inside diesel is a peer-dependency I guess, but why it cause this since it is different from the main cargo.toml